# Useful books to master Salesforce

Tags: apex, architecture

I'm considering buying some books to improve my Salesforce skills.

I found this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Library) on the Salesforce developer platform.

The three first books of the list "Books by Community Authors" seem to be the most interesting for me.

- *Advanced Apex Programming for Salesforce and Force.com*: Because there are moments when we have to use Apex. And I have already some knowledge with Apex.
- *Practical Salesforce.com Development Without Code*: Because as @AdrianLarson often says: "The more there is code, the more there is code to maintain."
- *Force.com Enterprise Architecture*: To help me make the best decisions to answer company problems.

**So my questions are:**

- Did anyone read these books? If so, were they helpful?
- Is there any other book in this list that I should read first?
- Is there any other book not in this list that is worth buying before them?

Comment: This is probably better asked on Meta.

Comment: Sorry. I have considered asking on Meta but I changed my mind after having read [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: I understand! I would just argue this falls under the `[discussion]` tag, because "what is a good book" doesn't have an objective answer. :)

Comment: @DanJones Should I add the [discussion] tag in the title of my question?

Comment: I'd say that this should go into Meta too. I do think it can be a suitable topic for here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it should  be migrated to Meta

Comment: I disagree. This question has nothing to do with stack exchange mechanics and would certainly be off topic there. If it's off topic, then vote to close it for whatever reason you see fit. But migration doesn't seem correct in this case.

Comment: _Force.com Enterprise Architecture_ changed my life (well sort of) - but you should be an experienced developer before tackling this as it makes the most sense after you've gone down wrong paths and realized it without knowing how to do it better

Comment: I'm closing this topic. I'm sorry for this conttroversial question but I needed some advices from this community and I didn't know where to ask this. I got some nice and useful answers. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I own the first and last book and I can say they are completely worth it! I learn a lot thanks to them and improved a lot my coding skills and overall knowledge of the salesforce platform. I would totally recommend those!

Another book I also bough recommended by a Friend was Clean Code, although it's not salesforce related can be applied to any coding language.

I was lately considering this one would like to know opinions if it's worth: 
[Apex Design Patters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/178217365X)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I already read Clean Clode and I totally agree with you. Thank you for your review of the two books. I will take a look at the new one you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

While I love books, I think that they may not be the best way to improve your salesforce skills unless you've already exhausted the huge variety of free resources, such as:

- [Automation Champion](https://automationchampion.com/)
- [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/)
- [SFDC99](http://www.sfdc99.com/)
- [The Official Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/)
- [This Udacity Course](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-point-click-app-development--ud162)
- Training videos in Help & Training if you're a premium customer
- [Dreamforce videos](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF15/sessions.jsp#)

The problem with books about the Salesforce platform is that they become out of date so fast and you can typically find the same information for free.