# Any good blogs/books or roadmap to learn Development in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can someone help me learning Salesforce development with good recommendation of blogs or books. 
Thanks

Comment: [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home) is your best friend. For the books, here's another question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157721/useful-books-to-master-salesforce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get started with [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails) in salesforce thats the best place to learn with exercises. It will help you familiarize  with the basics of the  platform

Comment: Yes I'm learning a lot from Trailhead . Apart from that any other sites or blogs?